# Please explain the below Scala code

Tags: scala

```
object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println( apply( layout, 10) )
   }

   def apply(f: Int => String, v: Int) = f(v)

   def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
}
```

In the function `def layout[A](x: A)`, what does `[A]` signify?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/782/type-parameterization-generics#t=201610012036290314627

Comment: Before asking Scala questions, why not learn the basics of the language first?

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic class in Scala. http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/generic-classes.html

If you know java then `[A]` is equivalent to `<A>` in Java.

The equivalent Java code will look like:

```
<A> String layout(A x){
   return "[" + x.toString() + "]";
}
```

Comment: so what is the use of it...i replaced def layout[A](x: A) with def layout(x: Int) and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: The difference is that a code with generics will work for any type of input. Whereas your code with Int x as argument will fail if you will call this method by passing parameter of any type other than Int.

Answer (score 1):

`[A]` declares a type parameter named `A`.

In Haskell-like syntax, this type would be written as

```
layout :: forall a. a -> String
```

Comment: so what is the use of it...i replaced def layout[A](x: A) with def layout(x: Int) and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: The parameterized function can be called with a value of any type. If you change the type of `x` to `Int`, then the function can only be called with values of type `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Non-generic methods are parameterized with known types:

```
def layout(x: Int) = "[" + x.toString() + "]" //parameter x is of a known type: Int
```

In the above example, x is explicitly set to be an Int. However, the toString method is applicable on any type in Scala. So, instead of writing multiple overloaded methods for different types like below:

```
def layout(x: Double) = "[" + x.toString() + "]" //parameter x is of a known type: Int 

def layout(x: List[Int]) = "[" + x.toString() + "]" //parameter x is of a known type: Int
```

We can write a single generic / polymorphic method by using type parameters:

```
def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
```

The `A` above is called a type parameter. Now, `A` could be of any type. Its an abstraction over the actual type.

You could now call the polymorphic `layout` method by explicitly specifying the type of `A`:

```
layout[Int](2)
```

Or you could simply call it like below, in which case Scala will automatically infer that the parameterized type `A` is of type Int:

```
layout(2)
```